# Difference between Operator [] overloading write/read?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading

I am new to C++ and I am sorry because of this question, but it is a struggle. If someone could help me to distinguish following lines, I would me grateful.

```
char& operator [](int);         // write (why with reference?)
char operator [](int) const;    //read (why without a reference?)
char const &operator[](int) const; // what is the difference compared to the previous line?
const char *& operator[] (const int* ); // is this also possible?
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to read an overview of [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706) .

So, to recap some applicable points:

- `operator[]` is *always* non-static unary member-function.
- There can be multiple overloads like for any other member-function.
- By convention (heed it!), non-const-qualified versions return a reference for modifying the content (That reference *might* be represented by a proxy-type, though try to yvoid that).
- By convention, `const`-qualified overloads can either return a `const` reference or a copy, to provide read-only access to the same elements.

  - Use a `const`-reference if the element cannot be dynamically generated, especially if it's not trivially and cheap to copy.
  - Use value-return, if the above does not hold.

BTW: You really want to have the `const` and non-`const` members be analogous, so the non-`const` can be a simple inline-function delegating to the other with the appropriate `const_cast`.
(Don't do it the other way around, that would not be quite allowed, or safe.)

Regarding your last line, that indexes with a pointer to `const int`, and returns a reference to a pointer to `const char`.
That is a seriously odd return-value and index, though if you have a valid use for it, why not?

Answer (score 3):

and just to ensure there is an answer with some code, here are some examples of the ways in which these versions might be used:

```
// Q: char& operator [](int);         // write (why with reference?)
// A: this is using [] to return a mutable reference to a conceptual element in my array
my_type x; // x supports operator []
x[6] = 'A'; // actually modifies the 7th element of x
```

-

```
// Q: char operator [](int) const;    //read (why without a reference?)
// A: this will return a COPY of the element at [i].
//    for a char this is irrelevant, a copy is trivial
//    if it was some large object you might want to return 
//    a const& instead and avoid the copy
char my_copy = x[6];
x[6] = 'B'; // from above
// now my_copy is 'A' but x[6] is 'B'
```

-

```
// Q: char const &operator[](int) const; // what is the difference compared to the previous line?
// A: as mentioned, for a char not a lot of difference. 
//    For a large object it avoids a copy
```

-

```
// Q: const char *& operator[] (const int* ); // is this also possible?
// A: yes it's possible. Yes it's completely evil. No, don't do it.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you overload operator `[]` like `char& operator [](int)`, it can read/write on the underlying `char` which is indexed by entry integer.

However in many cases you need to read properties of an `const` object, then you have to overload that operator by a `const` method, like `char operator [](int) const`.

The third one `char const &operator[](int) const` is useful as same as above, but when the underlying variable is `const`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said "When you overload operator [] like char& operator [](int), it can read/write on the underlying char which is indexed by entry integer." What is the difference if there is const in the end: char& operator [](int) const. It is still possible to read and write. Isn't it? If I overload operator by a const method, I can not see what is changed, it seems to be the same as the method wasn't const.

Comment: By putting `const` at the end of method, the method can not change the members (except mutable ones). So, you can just read. Moreover, returning `char&` is not useful anymore.

Comment: Main: String string("String"); string[3]='n'; But how this is possible? It compiles even though I used this method - char& operator [](int) const - to overload []. And I have not declared the member as mutable.

Comment: I'm sure it has an overload without `const` in order to allow changing the characters of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The first line tells you when you modify the value of operator[] returning, the old value will change too.

The second line tells you this operator can not modify any variable, but you can modify the value of return and don not change the old.

The third line tells you this operator can not modify any variable or value of return.

The difference between the second and third line is the former can modify the value of return,the latter can not modify the value of return as for the last, I am new to c++,too,so I don't know what it means.